# Everything is slow after installing 

Tags: installation, hp

i took the leap today. downloaded 12.04 LTS, burned the ISO to a CD ROM.

First i clicked the "try it out" option. Then i installed it on my HP Pavilion DV2000.

First time it started up, i downloaded some drivers, since there was no WIFI driver working. Also updated 2 NVIDIA drivers. it told me it needed to restart.

So I restarted...

When booting up it takes a looong time. Finally I can type in my password. it shows me the default background and nothing else. after about 30 seconds the background image sort of disolves. then come back. i wait around 5 - 10 minutes. Nothing happens at all.. just the orange default background. i hold down the power button. booting up again. same deal sort of. first i get to enter my password really quick. hit enter. default background image and mouse cursor icon. nothing else happens.

i wait for about 5 minutes, still nothing happens. i try right clicking. aha! i can create a new folder and change background. basically the standard Ubuntu right click on desktop menu. but the folder window and settings and everything else has no top navigation. like expand, minimize or the "x" close folder icon.

i look around what i can access, and i see that i have 130 updates. that could fix it i think to my self. update all.. still the same thing.

i kinda went all in and choose to only boot Ubuntu. No windows or anything else, so can anyone give some tips on what i could try to fix it?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what the actual issue is. Could you please update your question to clearly define what the problem is?

Comment: I edited the title. @martin can you edit the question so it is a bit more logical?

Comment: He installed Ubuntu and enjoyed it.Then he did some driver installation say Nvidia and for Wireless,now he is in pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said installed `2 Nvidia drivers`.I think both are mixed up and creating the problem.Please follow this(this is an answer for another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128113/how-do-you-remove-nvidias-proprietary-drivers) which I copy here)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

If you type that into the terminal, it will remove the propriatry drivers and go back to the stock drivers. I was having a similar issue and reformed the other day to figure out that the issues seem to be from the latest propriatary drivers. Once I uninstalled it and rebooted, everything was back to normal. Hope it helps!
(Thanx to [Tommy](https://askubuntu.com/users/58440/tommy))

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled 12.04 three times before i got it to work right... I have found its easier to start over than it is to fix an error ....getting nvidia working right first thing made all the difference. 
If i were you i would reinstall and before ever logging in go to repair option and go to a prompt then follow the following commands ...

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then.. sudo su   ...and type..  reboot

(the x-server is just as important as the drivers you need it all) maybe try all this at repair or any prompt (ctrl+alt+f1) before reinstalling it might fix it all 
if you try before reinstalling do this first to remove anything that might be in the way

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current
```