# Why does Ubuntu gets stuck on the loading screen?

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, graphics

I've been experiencing many problem lately since I fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
on my SONY VAIO VPCEH with Windows 7 previously installed.

Sometimes when I try to boot Ubuntu, it gets stuck at loading screen.
There seems to be some problem with driver (as far I can judge).

Following is the log generated, when I press `Esc` during the boot (before the
problem occurs):

```
...
* Stopping System V initialization compatibility        [ok]
* Starting System V runlevel compatibility              [ok]
* Starting crash report submission daemon               [ok]
* Starting automatic crash report generation            [ok]
...
...
* Starting LightDM Display Manager                      [ok]
```

Nothing works after that, no `Esc`, etc, except restart.

Also I've observed the following:

- Inactivity of Hard-drive (Led doesn't glows).
- Flashing, or blinking, of Caps-lock and Scroll-lock

On restart, Ubuntu seem to load successfully. However, the loading
screen has somewhat basic graphics.

This problem started after I installed Additional drivers:

```
NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver
```

Also, most of the times Ubuntu loads without any problem. However, it
is annoying to restart everytime it fails.

So my question is:

Why this happens and what is the solution?

Comment: Please edit your grub boot entry to remove "quiet splash" and instead insert "nomodeset". Does this allow you to boot?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the proprietary NVIDIA drivers are the cause of your problem. See the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128113/how-do-you-remove-nvidias-proprietary-drivers).

You can remove these drivers (using the Additional Drivers panel), but then you are stuck with the open drivers ([nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/)), which are limited.

Also, read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Furthermore, there is a [PPA](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/09/nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html) supposedly distributing the newest version of the Nvidia drivers, but apparently some people run into problems with these drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here: [14.04 Freeze on Splash after Installing NVIDIA Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582377/14-04-freeze-on-splash-after-installing-nvidia-drivers)

I had a similar problem after installing the nvidia drivers, but it happened to me every time I booted up, not just sporadically. These steps seem crazy, but they worked for me. All other solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by simply removing all the proprietary drivers and left the default generic one. Since I use my laptop just for working purposes it works like a charm.