# 14.04 Freeze on Splash after Installing NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, freeze

First of all, I have looked at a bunch of threads that are similar, but none of the solutions work for me. I am trying to install nvidia drivers (nvidia-340, specifically) but when I reboot the system always hangs after showing the purple splash screen. I can also hear the login drum sound, but I just see black. Up until now, the only solution has been to uninstall the driver and boot in again.

I have tried

- Changing `/etc/default/grub` to change the resolution on startup, among other items in this file
- trying different versions of the driver, including the proprietary one direct from nvidia

I have an ASUS N751JK and am dual booting with Windows, should that make any difference.

Any other ideas about what I can try? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complicated answer here that worked for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1362848

I fixed the problem with my nvidia graphic card using the post #15.

Thank you very much kcpr (mkasprzyk5) without your help I would not be albe to fix it.

Here how I fixed in details:

Log out and go to the console:

```
CTRL-ALT-F1
```

If (like me) you tried to install latest nvidia driver (nvidia-340 ...), you need to revert back with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then copy all xorg config files in a temporary dir:

```
cd
mkdir temp
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf* ./temp/

Then clean, update, upgrade and reboot the system:

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Go to the console:

```
CTRL-ALT-F1
```

Install nvidia 331:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

Copy the old xorg.conf made by nvidia back in its directory:

```
sudo cp temp/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And edit it (I used vi, you may prefer nano):

```
sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

To be as the following:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Eventually reboot the system:

```
sudo reboot
```

Now I have nvidia set as graphic card and the hardware acceleration works fine.

Comment: ---skaz,
You have two "Screen" sections in the config file. Is one supposed to be "Monitor"?