# I cant boot with new (3.11.6) or custom kernel

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel, lubuntu

I was trying compiled my own kernel, after it didn't work i downloaded latest official kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.6-saucy/ for my

Lubuntu 12.04 3.2.0-55-generic i386 netbook.

> I installed official kernel with these commands http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kernel-3-11-6-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-debian-pear-os-and-elementary-os/ (i386) . I can normally boot with 3.2.0-55-generic (default kernel). So is problem in some configurations or version (for v3.11.6-"saucy salamander" only?)?
>
> > My boot log:
> >
> > > `http://pastebin.com/JLreENgN`

Comment: After installing a the latest kernel give a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360416/latest-kernel-not-working/360431#360431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Precise you can install the [Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) (read the page thoroughly because there are caveats).

It's likely that your newly kidnapped kernel is incompatible with the rest of the graphics stack. There's quite a bit of work between 3.2 and 3.11. By getting the rest of the stack, you stand much better chance of booting. And it's all maintained for you.

Edit: I'm not sure if the 13.10 HWE stack is released yet but even the 13.04 is a year of progress from your stock 12.04 stack.