# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia problems after update

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, login

I updated a laptop a couple of days ago and I can no longer completely boot into UBuntu. Once it gets to the login screen, I can login but will never reach the desktop. The screen goes black eventually reboots back to the login screen. Trying to switch to any of the terminals just gives me a blank screen. So, I have no way of running commands. I suspect that there's a problem with the nVidia driver (it wouldn't be the first time). Is there any way to prevent UBuntu from loading the nVidia driver?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) for possible fixes.

Comment: How did you install nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try guest mode, just to see if you get in.  I'm not sure, but I think that once in guest mode you can enter the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/) using SUDO in the terminal (install if necessary).

Provided you have already installed it, the command to run it from terminal in guest mode would (probably) be:

> sudo synaptic

With synaptic you can do a search for your nvidia drivers and delete the driver.  Please only eliminate the enumerated driver, ie v 3.04 or 3.31, not all files associated with nvidia.  You need to keep some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problems on Kubuntu 15.04 :-/
The solution that should work on any actual linux version is to deinstall the NVIDIA drivers:

Switch to console with Strg+Alt+F1 and login

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-340
```

as desrcibed at: 
[How do you remove Nvidia's proprietary drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128113/how-do-you-remove-nvidias-proprietary-drivers)
and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia